# How I can show data from local json file using axios in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make some mockup data and call it. since my backend is not completed yet .

Comment: You can try with [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)

Answer (score 2):

You could serve the JSON locally.  You could run something like [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) in the background, say on port 5000, and make your requests to `http://<your computer's ip>:5000`.

Note: don't use `http://localhost:5000` - this will only work on the iOS simulator, since it's the only "device" that shares your local machine's network config.  Get the IP address of your computer and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe reading a local file with Axios is a wrong approach.

Check this link: https://dev.to/buaiscia/mock-an-axios-call-with-a-json-file-1j49

Instead, I recommend using FileSystem!

You can read local data in javascript using FileSystem.
Steps:

1. Install fs

   ```
   npm install fs
   ```
2. Import **fs** in file

   ```
   var fs = require('fs')
   ```
3. Then read the file:

   ```
   fs.readFileSync('fileName.json');
   ```